# SSL Certificate for Multiple Docker Containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I Have multiple Docker containers exposing their respective ports which I am bringing up using docker-compose, I have a service which is running on port 80.
I need to add SSL Certificate for all those Containers, Such that the application running on port 80 will be https

Answer (score 1):

You can either keep certificate on a reverse proxy or propagate through service configuration tools - which one depends on your infrastructure. One example might be [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/)

Comment: How can i keep Certificate on Nginx Reverse Proxy, Can you give me Example?

Comment: There are probably hundreds of articles describing the process. Eg https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04